# Simple Random Walk being conditioned not to hit certain value

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, random-walk

Consider $(S_n)_n$ a simple random walk, $S_n = \sum_k^n X_k$ where $(X_k)_k$ are i.i.d. random variables with $P(X_k = 1) = P(X_k=-1) = \frac 1 2.$ We further set $X_0=1$ and stop the random walk once it reaches $0$, i.e. $S_n=0$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. Also, define an *excursion from $l$ to $l+1$* of such a random walk as a part of the process where $S_m = l$ and $S_n = l+1$ for some $m<n$ and $l\in\mathbb Z$.

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $l,K\in\mathbb N, l < K$. The expected number of excursions from $l$ to $l+1$ of such a simple random walk **conditioned not to hit K,** is approximately $$ \left[ 1-\frac{l+1}K \right]^2. $$

So far, I have not made any significant progress. Thus, I'd be glad about any kind of help!

Comment: $[1+\frac{l+1}{K}]^2$ doesn't seem like an integer for "expected number of excursions"

Comment: @RahulMadhavan Indeed. I guess that's why is says "approximately".

Comment: Sorry my comment should have read $[1-\frac{l+1}{K}]^2$, and $\frac{l+1}{K}$ is bounded above by 1 as $K>l$ (and bounded below by 0). 
So $[1-\frac{l+1}{K}]^2 \in [0,1]$?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan I do see your point. However, for example with a coin flip, the expected number of heads is for example $\frac 1 2$ when you have a fair coin.

Comment: Yes indeed. In my opinion, the better way to express it would be probability of an excursion from l to l+1 such that K is not hit. Just like in the coin toss example, the better way to express it might be "probability of heads"

Comment: There seems to be another issue. Let K be l+2 for some large l. To get to K, one has to go through l+1. With probability $\frac{1}{2}$, the random walk hits $l+1$, and even after hitting $l+1$, the random walk comes back to $l+1$ without hitting K about $1/2$ the time. It seems the probability of a random walk from $l$ to $l+1$ not hitting $K$ is close to $1/2$. But $[1-\frac{l+1}{l+2}] \sim 0$?

Comment: What do you mean by "with probability $\frac 1 2$ the random walk hits $l+1$" ? Why is that the case? I understand what you say afterwards though, that once the random walk is at $l+1$ it will hit either $K$ or $l$ by probability $\frac 1 2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122753/discussion-between-rahul-madhavan-and-simon).